# Magento vat applied incorrectly

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.5

I'm having some problems with prices that are showing up wrongly. I have set up magento so that the prices i give to products are Including VAT. Yet it seems to just ignore the setting since even changing it won't change the result.
I've made some screenshots of the problem:

- [The VAT Settings](http://i54.tinypic.com/2cfccic.png)
- [The product price (backend)](http://i56.tinypic.com/205z120.png)
- [The product
  price (frontend)](http://i52.tinypic.com/2cxjij8.png)

Anyone has any idea what could be the problem?
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not into the tax rules in your country, but probably you have to change the calculation to be based on "shipping origin" and define the origin under "system > configuration > shipping settings > origin".

Calculation based on billing address requires an address set - which is probably not the case in the frontend (unless as a logged in customer). However, the tax should be correctly in the review step of the checkout.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is really related. my problem is that i want to enter the prices with vat included into the products but magento will still add VAT even when the it is set up to not do so. removing the VAT from the product will make it display the correct price but that would ruin the invoices etc.